# Using jQuery hover() to make element appear but not triggering animation twice

Tags: jquery

I'm building a simple slider with jCycle. 
When you hover over the slider, I'd like the 'previous' and 'next' arrows to appear. Once the cursor leaves the slider, I'd like the arrows to disappear again. The arrows are absolutely positioned over the slider.

The HTML for the slider:

```
        <div id="next"></div>
        <div id="prev"></div>

        <ul id="s2">            
            <li><img src="bla1" /></li> 
            <li><img src="bla2" /></li>
            <li><img src="bla3" /></li> 
            <li><img src="bla3" /></li>             
        </ul>
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
jQuery('#s2,#next,#prev').hover( function () {
    jQuery('#next,#prev').animate({opacity: 0.9});
},
function () {
    jQuery('#next,#prev').animate({opacity: 0});
});
```

This works, but it triggers the animation two times: when you hover over the slider and when you hover over the arrow element (#next or #prev).

How can I make the animation trigger only once?

For an example, please see http://fc.boilerroom.tv/.

Comment: You will get faster and better answers if you include the relevant slider HTML in your post rather than make people try to find it in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `#next, #prev` from the first selector and use a parent object of the next, prev instead:

```
jQuery('#container-main .ticker').hover( function () {
    jQuery('#next,#prev').stop(true).animate({opacity: 0.9});
},
function () {
    jQuery('#next,#prev').stop(true).animate({opacity: 0});
});
```

Note: I also added `.stop(true)` so it works fine if you go in and out of the hover quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#next, #prev` from your first selection ... leave just `jQuery('#s2')`

Comment: Because your #next, #prev elements are inside your #s2.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. Once the cursor hovers over #next or #prev, the animation triggers again.